# Boolean Not Working The Way I Think It's Supposed To

Tags: modifiers

So When I do a Boolean Modifier on the Sphere, and select a torus surrounding that sphere, I expect it to do what it first did in the middle, but it just cuts a hold straight through it.[image: The Problem]

Comment: Hi, can you show or describe better the boolean setup? Not too clear to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the type to carve and try to change between difference , intersect ... untill you get the wanted result